# Django REST Framework: Updating via UpdateAPIView vs RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView / Prefilled Form in Browsable API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I try to update a model instance via the `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` I can see the instance's values prefilled in the form in the browsable API. However, when I use `generics.UpdateAPIView` I can't. Is this due to the fact that `UpdateAPIView` does not allow GET methods, so the view can't get the data to prefill the form or is there a special setting I need to add in my `generics.UpdateAPIView` to have the form prefilled automatically

[image: Browsable API via generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView]

[image: Browsable API via generics.UpdateView]

Comment: The pre-fill is from the retrieve part of `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` so yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefilling part is due to the "Retrieve" part of the "generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView" you're calling, it retrieve and display the field values of the model instance you are querying.
You can use read this for further details and understanding; [RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview).

You can test this by putting an "issuperuser" read-permission on the view and logging in with a staff or normal user account to see what happens.